# SocketException caught in Selenium HtmlUnitDriver program

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I have written a small script that takes the default IP address for Epson printers we receive at my company and changes them automatically according to the requirement. This is done using Selenium HtmlUnitDriver.

The script gets the page, inserts the new IP, and than submits it. Because the IP changes once we submit a second time, the page is no longer `192.168.192.168`, and the script does not want to complete.

Below is the script:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Creating a new instance of the HTML unit driver.
        WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
        driver.get("http://192.168.192.168/ctcpip.htm");

        // Find and change the IP Address field.
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("IpAddress"));
        element.clear();
        element.sendKeys("192.168.192.169");
        element.submit();

        // Reset the printer. This changes it's IP as well, causing the initial driver page to no longer exist.
        WebElement reset = driver.findElement(By.name("Submit"));
        reset.submit();

        // The script never gets this far.
        driver.quit();

    }
}
```

The script times out before it can complete. When the `reset` element is clicked, the initial URL of `http://192.168.192.168/ctcpip.htm` is effectively nonexistent, since we have changed it to `192.169.192.169`. This is expected behavior, and the entire point of the program.

The console reads:

```
Nov 03, 2016 10:36:52 AM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {}->http://192.168.192.168:80: Operation timed out
Nov 03, 2016 10:36:52 AM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {}->http://192.168.192.168:80
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 192.168.192.168:80 [/192.168.192.168] failed: Operation timed out
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.doProcessPostponedActions(JavaScriptEngine.java:739)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.processPostponedActions(JavaScriptEngine.java:820)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.click(HtmlElement.java:1325)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.click(HtmlElement.java:1268)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.click(HtmlElement.java:1216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitWebElement.submit(HtmlUnitWebElement.java:175)
    at Main.main(Main.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 192.168.192.168:80 [/192.168.192.168] failed: Operation timed out
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:140)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:318)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:363)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:219)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.getResponse(HttpWebConnection.java:178)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseFromWebConnection(WebClient.java:1313)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponse(WebClient.java:1230)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:338)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WaitingRefreshHandler.handleRefresh(WaitingRefreshHandler.java:92)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeRefreshIfNeeded(HtmlPage.java:1446)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.initialize(HtmlPage.java:306)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:475)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadDownloadedResponses(WebClient.java:2074)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.doProcessPostponedActions(JavaScriptEngine.java:733)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:72)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:123)
    ... 29 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**How do I tell my driver instance that it's totally cool the page changed so the process can exit properly?**

The script **needs** to reach the `driver.quit();` line.

Comment: The script lacks synchronization. Use a sync method After this block of code -> element.sendKeys("192.168.192.169");         element.submit();

Comment: For the moment try using a thread.sleep and if you get the same exception. Just a shot in the dark here.

Comment: @Sai Sadly didn't work. Trying to see if I can do something with an implicit/explicit wait.

Comment: @jagdpanzer what happen after changing the IPAddress? Does the page refresh? Does it re-open window?

Comment: @Buaban The page attempts to refresh, which will always fail due to the IPAddress changing (seeing as the IPAddress is what we are using to connect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to call

```
driver.quit();
```

before

```
reset.submit();
```

? You no longer use the driver to retrieve any element, so you can quit before submitting the page.

I hope it helps.

Comment: how come quitting the browser can solve the issue before clicking on reset button?. If you know that IP can change and causes SocketTimeOutException, it is more of an exception handling (as you already know that an exception could arise) problem rather than quitting the browser before clicking reset button. If you call driver.quit before reset.submit, then reset button code will never be called. is that the behaviour you expecting?

Answer (score 1):

If something doesn't work with findelement in Selenium, everyone uses js :).
How about this ?

```
 driver.executeScript("window.document.getElementsByName("Submit")[0].click()");
```

Index could be wrong and need to be adjusted

Comment: Using `js.executeScript("window.document.getElementsByName('Submit')[0].click()");` causes a time out error - it can't find the Element.

Comment: what this returns (just in web console) ?
`window.document.getElementsByName('Submit'‌​)`

Comment: My issue isn't that click. That click goes through, and the printer successfully resets to the new IP address, but the script will not exit properly which keeps me from operating concurrently.

Comment: can you fake/forge GET (?) request ? :)

Comment: would that be making another `driver.get()`? Like, `driver.get(http://192.168.192.169/)`?

Comment: only one, which substitutes 1st get, sendkeys and submit

Comment: I apologize, but I do not understand.

Answer (score 1):

### Please try With the following Code :

It quits the driver in case of the provided Host or Host IPaddress is not available within the network.

---

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Creating a new instance of the HTML unit driver.
        WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
        try{
            driver.get("http://192.168.192.168/ctcpip.htm");
            WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("IpAddress"));
            element.clear();
            element.sendKeys("192.168.192.169");
            element.submit();

        // Reset the printer. This changes it's IP as well, causing the   initial driver page to no longer exist.
            WebElement reset = driver.findElement(By.name("Submit"));
            reset.submit();
        }
        catch(HttpHostConnectException e){
            System.out.println("Host Not Found : "+ e.getMessage())
        }

        finally{
        driver.quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: HttpHostConnectException is an unchecked exception. The catching of HttpHostConnectException did not compile for me.

Comment: For any Exception if you are handling using try and catch or throws(giving a signal to compiler I am aware of it) won't give you any problem while compiling the code. If you are getting kindly check for any library missing in the class path. In specific Http Client library